# Prove that the square of this complex function is the identity.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> For $z\in\mathbb{C}\backslash(−\infty, 0]$, let
> $$f(z):=\sqrt{|z|}\frac{z+|z|}{|z+|z||}$$
> Show that $f(z)^2 = z$.

I've tried considering $z=a+ib$ and also used a combination of complex conjugate laws and the fact that $|z|=\sqrt{z\overline{z}}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

No matter what approach I use, I get stuck somewhere. So, I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: I think the key is to express $|z+|z||^2$ as $(z+|z|)(\overline{z}+|z|)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $|z+|z||^2=(z+|z|)(\overline{z+|z|})$ we have, if $z+|z|\neq0$, that
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(z)^2&=&\left(\sqrt{|z|}\frac{z+|z|}{|z+|z||}\right)^2\\
&=&\sqrt{|z|}^2\frac{(z+|z|)^2}{|z+|z||^2}\\
&=&|z|\frac{(z+|z|)^2}{(z+|z|)(\overline{z+|z|})}\\
&=&|z|\frac{z+|z|}{\overline{z+|z|}},\\
&=&|z|\frac{z+|z|}{\overline{z}+|z|},
\end{eqnarray*}
and so it follows that
$$(\overline{z}+|z|)f(z)^2=|z|(z+|z|)=|z|z+|z|^2=(\overline{z}+|z|)z.$$
Then because $z+|z|\neq0$ also $\overline{z}+|z|\neq0$ and so $f(z)^2=z$.

Answer (score 1):

You have\begin{align}\left(\sqrt{|z|}\frac{z+|z|}{\bigl|z+|z|\bigr|}\right)^2&=|z|\frac{\bigl(z+|z|\bigr)^2}{\bigl|z+|z|\bigr|^2}\\&=|z|\frac{z^2+|z|^2+2z|z|}{\bigl(z+|z|\bigr)\left(\overline z+|z|\right)}\\&=|z|\frac{z^2+|z|^2+2z|z|}{2|z|^2+z|z|+\overline z|z|}\\&=\frac{z\left(z+\overline z+2|z|\right)}{2|z|+z+\overline z}\\&=z.\end{align}